# What kind of "removable" drive does Windows Easy Transfer require?

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, windows-easy-transfer

I am trying to save my Windows Easy Transfer MIG file to an external hard drive, but Windows Easy Transfer is refusing to put it there because it isn't treating that drive as "removable". Is there a way to convince it to save it there anyway? If it matters at all, I'm trying to transfer from Windows 7 Ultimate to Windows 8.1 Pro.

Comment: Weird, I've saved my WET files to the HDD in the PC many times before, which of course is not removable.  I've used it those times to transfer a user's account data from a local account to a domain account (after joining a domain).  Only one PC involved in those cases, no USB or network needed.  What's the exact message you get when trying to save it to that drive?

Comment: I was able to resolve it by saving to a networked share, but I really wanted to get it on the external hard drive. Unfortunately, I saw your question right after I did this work-around. The message said something about having to use a removable drive. Perhaps reading this would have clarified things for me better. http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/transfer-your-data-with-windows-easy-transfer/